# Insert Data to wordpress database table using php?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I need To add an IP address in the database table. But when submit click doesn't store values in the database
Please tell me how can I change

> 

.input-box input { padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid #999; } .btn { cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid #a8093a; color: #fff; background-color: #a8093a; } .btn:hover { background-color: #a8093a; border-color:#a8093a; } .btn:focus { outline: 0; } .input-box a { color: red; font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none; } .input-box a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

insert( 'wp_5wbtdj_ip_based_login', array( 'username' => $_POST['username'], 'start' => $_POST['start'], 'end' => $_POST['start'], array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ) ); echo "
Your data has been Inserted. Thanks!

"; } else { echo "

There was an error. Try again, please!

"; } ?> IP Based Login

Add IP Range Username

Adding IP Address

$(document).ready(function () { // allowed maximum input fields var max_input = 5000; // initialize the counter for textbox var x = 1; // handle click event on Add More button $('.add-btn').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); if (x Remove `); // add input field } }); // handle click event of the remove link $('.wrapper').on("click", ".remove-lnk", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); // remove input field x--; // decrement the counter }) });

Comment: You provided no information so we can't help you. Share your code, explain in greater detail the process, provide as much relevant information as you can. This question is not enough to help you with anything

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the 
[Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)